# Force User Control (specifically ListView) to Refresh Every Time Page Posts Back

Tags: asp.net, listview, postback

I have 2 user controls in a page, and when 1 posts back and does work (uploading a file), I'd like the other (a list of all the files uploaded) to refresh properly.

The user control that needs to refresh pretty much only contains a ListView with a custom datasource populated through a LINQ to Entities query.

There are no UpdatePanels and no AJAX involved. (AJAX is out of the question at this point, because learning every other little thing in .NET is already time-consuming enough; I'd like to not open the AJAX can of worms yet, no matter how much I'd like to learn it in general.)

So basically I want to know how to make the darn ListView update itself anytime anything on the page posts back - whether it's in a user control or not, whether it's another user control, the page, or whatever else posting back, and without utterly reloading the page through a redirection.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, nevermind, I guess.
Making it update its datasource during PreRender worked for my purpose, and actually, now that I think about it, is likely the reason the ListView was not updating otherwise. It was updating on Load, before the other user control had the chance to do its stuff.

However, I apparently can't just run my function to update its datasource at PreRender, because that made funky things happen with the Javascript (confirming delete). I don't know why that would be. I may have to test what that's about further.

So, right now I just run it on Load and PreRender (waste of resources, but at least it works as I want now).

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way of achieving what you want is to raise an event.

Let's say that;

- The user control that contains your FileUpload control is called uc1
- The user control that contains your ListView is called uc2

Then you need to;

- Get uc1 to raise an event
- Get the page to listen for that event and in the page's event handler, call a public function of uc2 to databind the ListView

Let us know if you need any code or examples.

Darren